# File string making directory and not file-name

Tags: java

When I create file in Java, it creates a folder with file-name + the file-type "extension" for example

```
String path = "C:"+File.separator+"hello"+File.separator+"hi.txt";
File f = new File(path);
f.mkdirs(); 
f.createNewFile();
```

this example creates a folder or directory named "hi.txt" and not a file as I expected. Why is this not making a file?

Comment: `f.getParentFile().mkdirs();`.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How is it supposed to distinguish when you want to create a file and when a folder (in reference to `mkdirs`)? The docs say: `Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname`.

Comment: I want to create file with type "txt" not folder

Comment: Aladdin use your magic lamp for the answer :) Kidding. You first used mkdirs which created whole path including hi.txt as folder, u first need to mkdir without hi.txt and then createNewFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you called `f.mkdirs();` first which created a directory with the given path. Create parent directory first using `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` and then create your file using `f.createNewFile()`:

```
String path = "C:"+File.separator+"hello"+File.separator+"hi.txt";
File f = new File(path);
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You first instruct the VM to create the directory `f` and then to create the file `f`. You want to create the **parent directory** of `f`, not the directory `f`:

```
File parent = f.getParentFile();
boolean ret = parent.mkdirs();
```

You should now check `ret`, just to know whether there were any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the directories represented by the *parent* path of `C:\hello\hi.txt`, which is `C:\hello`, and then create the file itself.

If you're using Java 7, the clearest way to achieve this is to use [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) as follows:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:", "hello", "hi.txt");
Files.createDirectories(path.getParent());
Files.createFile(path);
```